# Temperature conversion in C

Tags: c, beginner, converting

I have started to learn C and I have tried my hand at temperature conversion. The idea is to convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice/versa. Can somebody review my code and let me know how I might be able to improve it?  My program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void fahconv()
{
    double fah;
    puts("Enter value to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
    scanf("%lf",&fah);
    printf("Converted temperature from F to C: %lf",((fah - 32.0)*5.0)/9.0);
}

void celsconv()
{
    double cels;
    puts("Enter value to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit");
    scanf("%lf",&cels);
    printf("Converted temperature from C to F: %lf",(cels*9/5)+32);
}

void invalidchoice()
{
    printf("Invalid choice..exiting");
}

int main()
{
    char choice;
    puts("Enter (F or f) to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
    puts("Enter (C or c) to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit \n");
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'c': 
        case 'C': celsconv();
              break;
        case 'f': 
        case 'F': fahconv();
              break;
        default: invalidchoice();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering your preference for wide open space for curly-brace-delimited things, your math (and comma) operators feel a bit snug. Regarding the actual math, your use of floats in `fahconv` vs ints in `celsconv` is distracting and worries that reader that it might be significant.

Comment: Along with what everyone else said, I also notice you have added .0 to the numbers in one function but not in the other. Should probably add it to both.

Comment: can you perform mathematical operations between integers and doubles in C?  the variable `cels` is declared a double.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- You don't need `invalidchoice()` as it just prints a statement and nothing else.  Just put the `printf()` under `default`.
- Consider receiving all user input in `main()` and having the functions only do the calculations.  It's best to have a function do one (useful) thing.

  In this form, the functions could also *return* the values to `main()` and displayed.  With the user input eliminated, they should now take the original temperature as an argument.
- Optionally, you can return [`EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) instead of `0` or `1`, respectively.  It's *especially* important to return a failure value if the conversion was not successful.

You could then have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double fahconv(double fah)
{
    return (fah - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

double celsconv(double cels)
{
    return (cels * 9 / 5) + 32;
}

int main()
{
    double originalTemp;
    double convertedTemp;
    char choice;

    scanf("%lf", originalTemp);

    puts("Enter (F or f) to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius\n");
    puts("Enter (C or c) to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
              convertedTemp = celsconv(originalTemp);
              printf("Converted temperature from F to C: %lf", convertedTemp);
              break;
        case 'f': 
        case 'F':
              convertedTemp = fahconv(originalTemp);
              printf("Converted temperature from F to C: %lf", convertedTemp);
              break;
        default:
              printf("Invalid choice..exiting");
              return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Jamal had a lot of good points, so just a few short things to add:

---

`wordstogether` is a confusing naming scheme. You should do one of the more standard naming schemes. In particular, either `underscore_separator`, or `camelCase`. It's also fairly common to use `PascalCase` for structs in C.

---

Rather than celsconv, I would state what the conversion is from and to. For example,  `fahrenheit_to_celsius` and `celsius_to_fahrenheit`. Those make it immediately clear what the input is and what the output is. From the declaration, it's easy to see what they take, but their usage is more ambiguous (`fahconv(deg)` -- is `deg` Celsius? Kelvin?).

---

Since the performance of the switch is not a concern (it's not in a tight loop for example), I would be tempted to use `tolower` (from `ctype.h`) to simplify the switch to only have 1 case per character:

```
switch (tolower(choice)) {
    case 'c':
        /* celsius stuff */
        break;
    case 'f':
        /* ... */
        break;
    default:
        /* ... */
}
```

---

You should verify that all of the readings are successful. Otherwise, your later use of those variables are pretty dangerous/pointless. `scanf` returns the number of tokens successfully extracted, so the simplest way to verify it's success is to check `number read == number expected`.

Example:

```
double example;
if (scanf("%lf", &example) == 1) {
    /* success */
} else {
    /* failed :( */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

My C is a bit rusty, but here's what I can do about it:

`celsconv` and `fahconv` seem redundant. You can simply ask the user the input value and in what way to convert it. Then in your switch, do the conversion. Afterwards output the result. The following is the shortest I could get it, minus some cosmetics.

```
double input;
char convertTo;

scanf("%f",&input);
scanf("%c",&convertTo);

switch(convertTo){
  case 'c':
  case 'C':
    printf("F to C: %f",(input - 32) * 5 / 9); 
    break;
  case 'f':
  case 'F': 
    printf("C to F: %f",(input * 9 / 5) + 32); 
    break;
  default: 
    printf("Invalid choice..exiting");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps in this simple case. However, getting into the habit of breaking things up into functions early is a good habit - personally I'd rather recommend leaving them as functions.

Comment: @Yuushi I forgot OP did say he was learning, so yeah, point taken. :D

Answer (score 6):

Another choice is not to write an interactive program but to put the arguments on the command line.  Many UNIX utilities take this simpler approach.  Here is your program written that way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static double f_to_c(double fah)
{
    return (fah - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

static double c_to_f(double cels)
{
    return (cels * 9 / 5) + 32;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        double t = strtod(argv[1], 0);
        printf("%.2lfC = %.2lfF\n", t, c_to_f(t));
        printf("%.2lfF = %.2lfC\n", t, f_to_c(t));
    } else {
        printf("Usage: %s value\n", argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I have renamed your functions to short name equivalents of `fahrenheit_to_celsius` and `celsius_to_fahrenheit` suggested by @Corbin.

You may not have learned about command-line arguments yet.   `argc` is the number of arguments on the command line including the command name itself.  `argv` is an array of the nul-terminated strings, one for the command (`argv[0]`) and one for each argument you typed (`argv[1]` etc).

If you name the compiled program `convert` and run it, it will print the two possible conversions:

```
$ ./convert 32
32.00C = 89.60F
32.00F = 0.00C
```

Comment: For a commandline usage, I would recommend putting a loop on argc, and converting all the values presented.

Comment: @William Morris - Thanks for this elegant snippet. I was wondering what is the purpose of having static before the functions?

Comment: Making functions `static` keeps their name local which avoids polluting the global namespace and makes some compiler optimizations possible.  For a single file program that has no significance, but it is good practice when writing larger programs.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint: Never use `scanf` to read numbers from a terminal.  If the user types in a letter, the input gets "stuck" - this and anything later in the same `scanf` will not parse any input.  (Read the spec for `scanf` to see what I mean.)

Best way to do this sort of thing:

1. Declare a buffer of size `MAX_INPUT_LENGTH` (of your choosing)
2. Use `fgets` to read a buffer of that size
3. Use `sscanf` to parse the number out.

The C library functions dealing with strings are a real disaster (as they can easily cause buffer overflow, among other problems).  It's annoying that the safest way to do something as simple as what you're doing is as complex as this.